# How to bundle a commonjs in vite?

Tags: vite, es6-modules, commonjs, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I am trying to bundle a dependency (named [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co)) that uses `require`, using `vite` so that I can use it for some client side javascript. I am aware that client side browser doesn't support node's `require` statements, as such, I am trying to bundle it using `vite` and essentially converting it to be browser friendly.

`vite` is using `rollup` under the hood so I should be able to accomplish this by using [@rollup/plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs#options) to vite's [build options](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-commonjsoptions).

Minimal `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { splitVendorChunkPlugin } from "vite";

import { resolve } from "path";

const extensions = [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"];

const root = resolve(__dirname, "src");
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, "docs");

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [splitVendorChunkPlugin()],

    base: "./",
    publicDir: false,
    mode: "Development",
    root,

    build: {
        target: "es2020",

        outDir,
        emptyOutDir: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: resolve(root, "script.ts"),
                flickity: resolve(root, "flickity", "flickity.pkgd.min.js"),

                index: resolve(root, "index.html"),
            },
        },

        modulePreload: {
            polyfill: false,
        },

        commonjsOptions: {
            extensions: extensions,
        },
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".cjs", ".mjs", ".js", ".mts", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json"],
        mainFields: ["module", "main", "jsnext:main", "browser"],
    },
});
```

With that tried, it still didn't worked and was still not converting the `require` statements.

> A portion of the output file is included here and as you can see, the `require` statement is still not converted:

```
var G=Object.defineProperty;var K=(r,i,c)=>i in r?G(r,i,{enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:c}):r[i]=c;var Y=(r,i)=>()=>(i||r((i={exports:{}}).exports,i),i.exports);var A=(r,i,c)=>(K(r,typeof i!="symbol"?i+"":i,c),c);import{a as _,$ as C}from"./vendor-8d31bf49.js";var nt=Y((ot,y)=>{/*!
 * Flickity PACKAGED v2.3.0
 * Touch, responsive, flickable carousels
 *
 * Licensed GPLv3 for open source use
 * or Flickity Commercial License for commercial use
 *
 * https://flickity.metafizzy.co
 * Copyright 2015-2021 Metafizzy
 */(function(r,i){typeof define=="function"&&define.amd?define("jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget",["jquery"],function(c){return i(r,c)}):typeof y=="object"&&y.exports?y.exports=i(r,require("jquery")):r.jQueryBridget=i(r,r.jQuery)})(window,function(i,c){var l=Array.prototype.slice,s=i.console,n=typeof s>"u"?function(){}:function(e)
--------------/* require statement is still here */-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

I am porting my project from `webpack` to `vite` so I am quite new to this. Could this be a bug on vite? rollup? or there's just something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that `vite` automatically manages the input javascript (commonjs `requires` for this matter) in order to make it browser friendly. My only problem is that I was using the wrong version of flickity. It currently it should be `2.3.0` but I was using `3.0.0`.

There must be some kind of issue with `3.0.0` with regards to its imports. I'd also like to add that you can install the specific version of flickity using:

```
npm install flickity@2.3.0
```

or just use the CDN

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```